# How to Set Preferences 'Translation Branches Directory' path to a valid directory?

Tags: modeling, rendering, texturing, materials, edit-mode

I wanted to Rename **IkeaShader** but it says **Please set your User Preferences 'Translation Branches Directory' path to a valid directory**. I have been searching it online, and playing around without success. See the image below.

[image]

Comment: Can you share a link to the acutal IKEA Shader/Add-on? I guess, the shader is coming from an add-on and you forgot to set that up properly...?

Comment: @brockmann actually, I downloaded the file from the Internet and the reason why I wanted to rename it was to make my work clean.  Because having various names like **Ikea001 Ikea002** and so on often confusing, since I'm working with colors. I'm sure you understand my explanation?

Comment: This one: http://blendermada.com/materials/detail/87-ikea-plastic/ ?

Comment: @brockmann yes. Since I downloaded the file from there, is it possible to rename the material  as it's shown in the previous image, in order to make my work clean?

Answer (score 1):

Enable the "developer extras" on Preferences -> Interface -> Display and then
the "translation Branches Directory" can be set on Preferences -> file Path -> Development ->  i18n Branches

related, see https://devtalk.blender.org/t/manage-ui-translations-addon-requires-translation-branches-directory-to-be-set/25926